# Flex: Need embedded SWF to be able to interact with project assets

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash, loader, swfloader

I have a Flex project in which I am embedding a Flash SWF containing an image viewer.  The SWF file I'm embedding is supplemented by an XML file, which contains a list of images to show, and an images folder containing the images.

The problem I'm running into is that the embedded SWF file is unable to load the pictures.  I am able to see the forward/backward navigation buttons, but there are no loaded images.  When I view the SWF file outside of the Flex project it works fine.  Is this because Flex isn't allowing the SWF to reach outside and access other project assets?  How can I get around this?

Here's my code for embedding the SWF:

```
<mx:Script>
<![CDATA[
    import mx.controls.Image;
    import mx.events.CloseEvent;
    import mx.managers.PopUpManager;

    [Embed(source = '../components/sampleReportViewer/photo_stack_gallery.swf')]
    [Bindable] public var SWFClass:Class;

    private function init():void {          
        //add the swf to the container
        var img:Image = new Image();
        img.source = MovieClip(new SWFClass());
        contentBox.addChild(img);       

        PopUpManager.centerPopUp(this);
    }
]]>
```

```
<mx:VBox id="contentBox"
    width="600" height="450"/>
```

Comment: Are you running the debug flash player if not please install it if so do you get any sort of errors during run-time, my guess is a security sandbox violation but without getting error messages this will be hard to diagnose and resolve, for more on loading modules and security contexts check here: 

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=modular_2.html

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=security2_01.html

Answer (score 1):

My guess is your workpath is not the same.  Judging from the relative paths in your url (`../`) you have a project structure that looks something like this:

```
|
index.html
|
+ swf
| |
|  main.swf
|
+ components
|
+ xml
```

If that is the case, your Flash player will assume the parent folder of index.html as your current workpath, if you load the HTML page into your browser, and all your `../` references won't find the correct resources, whereas if you start by double-clicking the swf directly, everything will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

First You should load images through loader,

> var loaderSmall:Loader=new Loader();
>   loaderSmall.load(new
>   URLRequest(imgArr[0].path));
>   loaderSmall.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS,loadThumbImage);
>   loaderSmall.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,hideThumbImageLoader);

Here,

> imgArr[0].path

is the path of the image which is to be loaded, now you can do lot more things, with this type of setup, now you can check, whether image is loading or not

This is one exmaple gallery, which i developed, it's not very perfect, but images i m loading is through loader,
http://no-refresh.com/demo/PortfolioSlideshow2/

In your problem , u shd first check the path, whether thats correct or not, may b sourec of image is not correct,

As @weltraumpirat has wrote, do check for that as well,

i know it won't help u, but n e ways, hoping it helps u smway, tc

Ankur